# Any way to get a BeanShell (or Scala, or JRuby) REPL in a pure Java Maven2 project?

Tags: java, scala, maven-2, read-eval-print-loop

I have a Java only project using Maven2. It'd be very useful to be able to get a REPL that has access to the full classpath of the compiled application and all libraries. In SBT, this is trivial for pure Scala and mixed Scala/Java projects: I run `sbt console`.

But it'd be very useful for pure Java projects too. I'm not bothered about what language: Scala, obviously, is pretty good for this, as is BeanShell, but JRuby or Jython or Rhino or Clojure would do the job pretty well too. Basically I want to be able to interactively poke and prod objects.

What's the simplest way to get a REPL set up in a Maven project without having BeanShell or Scala or whatever being added as a runtime/compile-time dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For JRuby, try the following. Does not require modifying your POM.

```
mvn org.jruby.plugins:jruby-rake-plugin:irb
```

Answer (score 0):

The GMaven plugin allows you to launch the [groovy shell / console](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Running+Groovy+Tools). This should have all the project dependencies in the classpath.